# Confused with chef syntax

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Look at the following line of chef code:

```
node.default['apache']['dir']          = '/etc/apache2'
```

In the official chef docs, it says 'node' is an object, and 'default' is a method of it, so how can square brackets(I thought this is hash syntax) follow a method?

I come from Python background and I'm new to Ruby, maybe this is general syntax, or maybe this is Chef-specific syntax, I'm just confused about this syntax.

Comment: Obviously, the `default` method on `node` returns something that has implemented the `[]` method - most likely an instance of `Hash`.

Comment: `default` returns a hash? That's really nothing special about Ruby, you could do the exact same thing in Python. Oh, and no, this isn't Chef-specific syntax. It *cannot* possibly be Chef-specific syntax, since Ruby, just like Python and 99.999% of programming languages, doesn't allow libraries to change its syntax. You may be thinking about something like Katahdin.

Comment: @spickermann Obviously? How is that obvious to someone that is "new to Ruby"? Ruby has lots of confusing features and generally poor documentation, "obvious" rarely applies to Ruby until you've internalized a lot of information.

Comment: Anyway, @Ursus had it right, `node.default['a']['b'] = ...` is just `obj = node.default(); obj['a']['b'] = ...` and that `obj` is something that behaves like a nested hash. You can trace through [the source](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb#L207) if you think that will help (get used to reading library source code if you're going to be doing Ruby, it is often the only way to figure out what's going on behind all the "magic").

Comment: @JörgWMittag lol, if func is a method that returns a dict in Python, can you use this kind of syntax: func['foo'] ?

Comment: @zanyman: In Python, Parentheses are mandatory for method calls, so you would have to use `func()['foo']`, but that is the exact same thing. Also, if `func` is a property that returns a dict, then you can even use the  exact same syntax: `func = { 'foo': 'bar' }; func['foo'] #>>> 'bar'`.

Answer (score 2):

`node.default()` (which is really an alias for `node.attributes().default()`) returns an instance of a `Chef::Node::VividMash` which works kind of like a normal `Hash` object but implements the deep-set behavior you see there (where you can set a deeply nested key without creating the intervening levels).

tl;dr don't worry about, we do a lot of object trickery to make the DSL look as nice as possible.